# office 365 Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

The HR department has 5000 unliscenced users. I want to remove them all. 
I'm confused between two powershell commands and want to use the fastest one:

```
## 1
Get-MsolUser -UnlicensedUsersOnly | Remove-MsolUser -force
## 2
Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.department -eq "HR"} | Remove-MsolUser -force
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't think that there would be a huge difference in processing time since you're just using two different ways of retrieving a list of data, it seems like it would be a little faster to just pull the unlicensed users, as opposed to pulling all users and then filtering them based on department. However, are you sure that there aren't any unlicensed users in other departments that you may not want to delete?

Regarding which command is faster, have you tried using the `Measure-Object` command to see how long each one will take? You could just measure the `Get-MsolUser` command to confirm the difference.

```
Measure-Object {Get-MsolUser -UnlicensedUsersOnly}
Measure-Object {Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.department -eq "HR"}}
```

`Remove-MsolUser -force` should take the same amount of time for both options. Also, I think you'll need to put the `Remove-MsolUser` command in a foreach loop:

```
foreach($user in Get-MsolUser -UnlicensedUsersOnly | where {$_.department -eq "HR"})
{Remove-MsolUser -ObjectId $user.ObjectId.guid -force}
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176899.aspx